# What is the probability that 4 employees complete their task in a total of 10 hours or more.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

A company expects its employees to finish a task at an average of 12 hours. What is the probability that 4 employees complete their tasks in a total of 10 hours or more?

Would this be a Poisson, binomial, or hypergeometric? It was posted by the instructor after learning about the aforementioned probability distributions

I am leaning toward poisson, solved in this manner:

$$ \lambda = 4 \text{ employees} * 12 \text{ average hours} = 48 \text{ hours} , $$
and the solution be $P(X > 10)$?

Thanks

Comment: There is no reason for us to think of a Poisson distribution here unless there is more information not in the question.  Indeed you question seems to be missing important information

Comment: There are infinitely many distributions that have a mean of $4$, of course, and we simply cannot answer the question without knowing the functional form of the distributions.

Comment: Well each success is independent, success seems to be in a given interval , and the mean for an interval is given, This is why I was thinking poisson.  IF we evaluate it using possion would I be evaluating this correctly?

Comment: What is the **background** of the problem?  Is this from a book or class?  If so, what theorems or previously solved problems (i.e. what training) do you think might be relevant?  For example, did your book/class just complete a section on poisson distributions?  Is there an implicit or explicit assumption (or more info) missing from the problem?  Please do **not** respond with a comment.  Instead please **edit your query** in response.

Comment: my apologies for not being clear.

Answer (score 1):

It is important you understand that, in most practical situations, a Poisson random variable counts the number of times a particular event occurs in a specific interval of time or a specific region of space. These events must be independent, two events cannot occur simultaneously, and the average number of events that occur in a specific interval of time or a specific region of space is approximately constant. In your scenario, an "event" corresponds to an employee completing his or her work task.

That being said, if $X$ denotes the number of tasks a single employee finishes in a one hour period, then $X \sim \text{Poisson}(1/12)$ assuming aforementioned conditions are met.

If $T$ represents the time it takes for an employee to complete his or her first task, you can show that $T\sim \text{Exponential}(1/12)$. The argument goes like this. For $t> 0$ we have $$P(T\leq t)=1-P(T>t)=1-P\Big(\text{No tasks completed in } [0,t]\Big)$$

The number of tasks an employee finishes in $[0,t]$ is $\text{Poisson}(t/12)$ so $$P\Big(\text{No tasks completed in } [0,t]\Big)=e^{-t/12}$$ Hence $P(T \leq t)=1-e^{-t/12}$ which shows $T\sim \text{Exponential}(1/12)$.

Now assume that the employees complete their tasks independently of each other. Let $T_1,T_2,T_3,T_4$ denote the times it takes for the employees to finish their first tasks. You're looking to compute the probability that $\max\{T_1,T_2,T_3,T_4\}\geq 10$. We get $$P\Big(\max\{T_1,T_2,T_3,T_4\}\geq 10\Big)=1-P\Big(\max\{T_1,T_2,T_3,T_4\}< 10\Big)=1-\Big(1-e^{-5/6}\Big)^4$$

Comment: The assumption that the length of time an employee takes to complete a typical task is exponentially distributed seems rather dubious to me.  Such a distribution would be appropriate if the distribution of the time to complete the task, *given* that some time $\ t\ $ has already been spent on it, is *independent of* $\ t\ $.  I would surmise that most tasks carried out by the employees of most businesses are unlikely to satisfy that condition.

Comment: This is very impressive, but this question was asked during a module on Poisson, binomial, or hypergeometric. We did not learn about T-exponential, is that part of Poisson?

Comment: @ lonza: I agree with you. The time is takes for an employee to complete a task is definitely certainly not memoryless. I also seriously doubt that the number of tasks completed in a one hour period following a Poisson random variable. I am just solving the problem in the spirit in which I believe it was intended to be solved.

Comment: @ RobBob: Thank you for your compliment. And yes, Poisson and Exponential random variables are intimately connected as I detailed in my response. If you're asked to find the probability that all four employees complete at least one tasks in ten hours or more, you need to find the distribution of the time it takes for all four employees to complete at least one task.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating and the response!

Comment: No problem, and please note @lonza leggiera's comment.

Comment: @Matthew Pilling. Yes, I agree that your answer is about the best you can do with the question as posed, given the apparent level of knowledge expected of the students who have to answer it.